# Sending commands from microcontroller to display via SPI and receiving results

Tags: c, interface, embedded, microcontroller, msp430

Ok, this question might be a little wide as I don't really know where to start with all this. I'll try to be clear.

I have a mobile phone display with a known display driver for wich I have the data sheet. This display will communicate with a micro controller (msp430g type) over SPI.

Some of the commands sent to the display does not yield a response but some do, the response might be several "bytes" (9 bits of data).

I first thought that I should have a fifo buffer to which the microcontroller fed commands so that the micro could do other stuff while the command is being shifted out. But I get the feeling that would "disconnect" the command from the possible response in the case where there is a response. And I don't know how to deal with that.

My second thought was to have all commands as functions that did the (write->[read*x]) that the command in question would need. But that feels like I will have the micro standing around waiting for the SPI interface way to much.

What is the "normal" thing to do in this case? I guess there are many answers but I'm sure a lot of code has been written that uses some interface to communicate with some device but do other stuff while the interface is "working".

If there is anything vague about what I'm trying to do, please just let me know and I'll try to clarify.

Comment: The answer will ultimately depend on things such as what action you would take based on the display's potential response, as well as what the delay is likely to be and what other tasks you have for the processor.

Comment: I am not posting it as answer but in general (at least in my projects) I consider following approach. In most of hardware (like displays, sensors etc) data sheet describes a timeframe within you can expect a response. At the end of the day communication between hardware and MCU is not guarantee delivery TCP.. so if you follow a strategy to wait specified amount of time before answer should arrive and then read it (or consider no answer/error) in case it's not arrived you should be fine.

Comment: You dont have to block you main loop to wait, just use timers or anything similar with a mark that you are expecting answer from certain device and then implement simple state machine with states like  (IDLE, AWAITING ANSWER, ERROR etc), which will be maintained by main loop or timer

Comment: @evilruff So basically just send the command (thats no more than writing to two registers), wait for a set time after wich the send should be done and then take action.

Comment: thats exactly what i mean

Answer (score 0):

SPI is master-slave, so to Rx from the slave (I'm assuming the display will be the slave) you need to **transmit** a dummy byte of data (so the master is waggling the clock line) and you should get the Rx data clocked in on your Rx (In/Rx/MISO) pin.

If there is a hardware SPI interface that can handle this autonomously then you can leave it all to work in the background & should get an interrupt when it's finished.

I can't speak for the MSP but on the Coldfire the SPI hardware can be loaded with some stuff to Tx/Rx and will go and do it, in your example you would append a dummy byte to the end of the Tx data and the reply byte would then be in the last slot in the RX buffer when the "ready" interrupt happened.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I'm aware of how SPI works though and my question is (at least intended to be) more about how to schedule the reads and writes in an efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule the reads and writes in an efficient way, I would recommend the use of interrupts. The MSP430 has an interrupt for both when a byte gets sent, and when a byte has been received. When the interrupt fires, load the next byte to be sent (for tx), or store the received byte (for rx). When your command has been sent, you can set a flag for getting a response if you expect one. When you have received a reply you can set a flag for your main loop to process the response.

Comment: I have thought of this. Thing is, I might run the spi at the same frequency as the micro. And the 6 clk overhead of the interrupt makes me think it's not worth it. But I'm still not sure. It would be convenient to handle the CS-line in a interrupt though, so maybe.